# How to get Maven multi-module project with separate Sonar project per module?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube

**Direct question:**

I need to get Maven multi-module project integrated with Sonar where each module will have 
separate Sonar project. Any working example how to achieve this? Maven version is 3.0.4 if it matters.

**Somewhat more detailed explanation why**

Yes, I have 100% working multi-module project which maps to single Sonar project key. But there is several reasons to break this beauty.

- I need integration with IntelliJ and currently the only option seems to take IntelliJ SonarQube plugin and it could support only different project key per module.
- I need different quality profiles and quality gates per module as they are too different.
- Project modules are going larger and I'd like to have separate tracking over them on Sonar side.

**Alternative ideas**

Other option looks like to get IntelliJ plugin to work on multi-module Maven project but this anyway does not solve separate quality tracking requirement on Sonar side. And I'm in doubt this is currently possible. I've tried even manually setting project keys per module on Idea side and this only results 1 module working.

Just to note, most of code under this engine is Java but there are also some Scala tools.

**RESOLUTION**

Agreed with @kraal. By this time I am already familiar with SONAR modules and plugins and SONAR 4.4 brings me flexibility I need without such a hacks with minimal plugin coding or additional processing configuration. Considered closed.

Comment: I think from Maven side there will be no any problems: just declare sonar plugin in parent project and add execution phases in each module. Connection properties can be also be stored per module. But I think that Sonar itself will group modules into one project hierarchy based on pom structure, just like before separation. So you need to make the test by yourself.

Comment: SONAR does not group in this case (if there are plugins configured on top layer and projects on modules layer). More, in this case I need to use maven profiles to 'hide' sub-modules from top level POM. But this is more or less OK. The only potential issue I need to check in this situation is the way SONAR exposes such projects to IntelliJ SonarQube plugin with incremental check. By now it looks like most robust approach for me. You've just added +1 to this idea (should be posted as answer :-) ).

Comment: Man, I'm developing software for more than 14 years, I don't care about any ratings anymore)

Comment: ... but this is funny game from time to time and game should have scoring ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that using maven multi-modules is the way to go in your case ?

If you always really need to release all modules simultaneously, if all modules have the same lifecycle (i.e. you're not in a situation where a module A is modified once per year and a module B is modified once per week) and if the size of each module is acceptable : ok.

Otherwise (if you sometimes release them separately or have stable code not modified anymore or which is rarely modified or if your modules start to be too big) I would rather try to create multiple projects in different SCM repositories instead of using multi-modules.

Think about it.

Edit : if you go the multi projects way, you can then aggregate the quality view using the portfolio plugin.